# C# retrieving subdirectories from selected directory

Tags: c#, file, file-upload, directory

I am trying to find a way to retrieve the subfolders from a selected directory. I have used FolderBrowserDialog inside of my code to all the user to select the "root" directory that the program will be using. But I am stuck on how to get the subdirectories from that. I want to plce these subdirectory string names inside an array to be used later. I tried using Directory.getFiles("the selected path"), but this does not display the subdirectories. 
Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you

```
 private void Folderselector_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(fileName);
                item.Tag = file;
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `Directory.GetDirectories(yourRootPath);`

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
var dirs = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetDirectories("*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
              .Select(d => d.FullName)
              .ToList();
```

and if you want the directory names relative to your root dir

```
var dirs = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetDirectories("*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
               .Select(d => d.FullName)
               .Select(s => new Uri(path).MakeRelative(new Uri(s)).ToString())
               .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the method overload with SearchOption.AllDirectories

Answer (score 0):

Close, but there's a different method for directories:

```
System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(string rootDirectory);
```

Comment: Couldn't you just run this over again to get the sub-sbu directories?

Answer (score 0):

```
System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(string rootDirectory);
```

With recursion is your solution

```
List<string> dirsResult = new List<string>();
public void GetDirectories(string currentDirectory)
{   
   string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(currentDirectory);
   foreach(var dir in directories)
   {
       dirsResult.Add(dir);
       GetDirectories(dir);
   }
}
```

I haven't tested it, but something like this should work.

Comment: You don't have to do it manually, passing `SearchOption.AllDirectories` to `Directory.GetDirectories`  would do it for you, as other answers already said.